# Gradle: updated dependencies not used

Tags: gradle, snapshot, artifactory

I'm new to builds using gradle. At the moment I try to implement a build of project B that uses the build result of project A, that is deployed to artifactory. I'm using Gradle 2.2. Details:

**Project A**'s build.gradle contains:

```
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'at.mic.projectA'
```

Applying plugin 'maven' leads to a new artifact like at.mic.projectA-1.0.0-20150624.073846-2.jar (and .pom) in artifatory each time project A is build.

**Project B**'s build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'at.mic.projectA', name: 'at.mic.projectA', version:'1.0.0+'
    ...
}
```

'at.mic.at.mic.projectA', version:'1.0.0+'
When project B is build for the first time, this dependency is resolved correctly and the newest at.mic.projectA-*.jar is downloaded from artifactory.

If I change some source of project A and re-build it I would expect two things during build of project B:

1. download of newest artifact at.mic.projectA-*.jar and
2. re-compilation of project B.

Unfortunatelly this doesn't happen. Even if I delete the contents of user_home/caches to force use of new artifacts, these were downloaded but gradle doesn't re-compile project B - it writes to log:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:uploadArchives
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration? Thanks in advance!

Frank

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the [default cache settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) for dynamic versions.

Comment: Thank you @BenManes, that was the solution I looked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was provided in Ben's comment:

*It sounds like you need to change the default cache settings for dynamic versions*

Thx, Ben